# Spring Integration tcp/ip connection delay

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, tcp

We are using Spring integration 4.1.3.

Sometimes it takes more than 5 seconds to request a connection from a particular server.

What is happening between step1 and step2?

Why is it delayed?

**Client Log**

```
step1 :▶ DEBUG 11.28 18:14:33.237  [ajp-bio-8109-exec-3] org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory[obtainNewConnection:98] - Opening new socket connection to 10.0.12.111:36401
step2 :▶ DEBUG 11.28 18:14:38.306  [ajp-bio-8109-exec-3] org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection[<init>:138] - New connection 10.0.12.111:36401:2701:561f3524-c421-45ba-9ea5-76a7ddf96430
```

**Client Config**

```
<int:gateway id="gw-vacct-tcp-sender"
             service-interface="com.mainpay.pay.service.TcpSendVacctGateway"
             default-request-channel="vacct-input"
             default-reply-channel="vacct-reply"
             />

<int-tcp:tcp-connection-factory id="vacct-client"
                                type="client"
                                host="#{springSetting['pay.pg.ngin.vip']}"
                                port="#{springSetting['pay.pg.ngin.vacct.port']}"
                                serializer="TCPJsonSerializer8"
                                deserializer="TCPJsonDeserializer8"
                                single-use="true" 
                                so-timeout="20000"      

/>      

<int:channel id="vacct-input" />

<int-tcp:tcp-outbound-gateway id="vacct-outGateway" 
                              request-channel="vacct-input"
                              reply-channel="vacct-reply" 
                              connection-factory="vacct-client"  
                              reply-timeout="20000"
                              />

<int:channel id="vacct-reply" datatype="java.lang.String" />
```

Comment: It's a test server and it's free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `lookup-host` to false; perhaps there is a problem in the network with reverse host lookups. It appears that the lookup failed since it is an ip address in the connection id.

```
10.0.12.111:36401:2701:561f3524-c421-45ba-9ea5-76a7ddf96430
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-connection-factories).

> By default, reverse DNS lookups are done on inbound packets to convert IP addresses to hostnames for use in message headers. In environments where DNS is not configured, this can cause connection delays. You can override this default behavior by setting the `lookup-host` attribute to false.

Comment: The connection delay issue no longer occurs. Thank you very much.